# Bootstrap v3 modal close event not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have tried all of the following code, and I cannot get the "hidden" modal event to fire. I have read the documentation, and every other SO question I can find, but still to no avail. I am using rails. Here is the code I have tried:

```
$('#signupmodal').on('hide.bs.modal', function() {
alert("hide");
});

$('#signupmodal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    alert('hidden event fired!');
});

$('#signupmodal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        alert("show");
    }, 300);
});

$(document.body).on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $('#signupmodal').removeData('bs.modal')
});

$(document).on('hidden.bs.modal', '#signupmodal', function (event) {
    alert("hide");
});
```

Any insight is greatly appreciated!

Comment: any error on Dev console?

Comment: nope, all libraries are loaded correctly, other jquery runs as expected as well. just this event will not fire.

Comment: can I see the site online?

Comment: its local development still

Comment: Yes, wrapped in isReady event to make sure

Comment: Does this help? https://github.com/jschr/bootstrap-modal/issues/228 -- Seems common

Comment: hmm....trying this now according to the issue, still not firing.                               $(document).ready(function() {
$('#signupmodal').on('hidden', function () {
console.log("hide")
});

Comment: is the modal dynamically created?

Comment: ahh, it is not. loaded topic seems to be somewhat in debate currently: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/6846

Comment: Share a fiddle. the community can help you out

Answer (score 0):

I almost don't want to admit this, delete my question and never speak of it again, but turns out jQuery was being loaded twice, and therefore I couldn't access Bootstrap JS.

Thank you for the help anyway! :)